# Huge difference between model and bake

Tags: baking

I am trying to bake a higher poly model to a lower poly and I'm not sure where I am going wrong. I am very new to blender, I've only been learning for a few weeks and this is my first time baking.

I am following a tutorial but I am getting black patches and extremely poor results. I have tried changing the ray distance everywhere between 0.0 and 1.0, and fiddled with the lighting and other settings with not much better output. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Settings].

[image: Render preview]

[image: Bad result]

Comment: have you checked the normals? Maybe share a part of your object (where it doesn't work): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I have tried 'Recalculate outside' but it did not do much. Here is the file - I did decimate the high poly to make it small enough to send. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/xw3JkBwW

Comment: you need to pack the images, otherwise there's nothing to bake, you can use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Hope I did this right! https://pasteall.org/blend/2bcc4ba74e76474a9da9b77d2d558c02

Comment: weird because when I try myself it works fine... are you in 2.8? because there may be a problem with 2.8, so try with 2.79 or 2.9?

Comment: @moonboots I am using 2.91 :/ I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for trying it! If its not too much trouble could you send me a screenshot of the result you get?

Comment: maybe create a new image and try again? here is the image: https://pasteall.org/pic/70d9e52b5b5c4d7fac90713f6d1cb8bc